# Unremovable Appendix Chapters in Thesis

Tags: appendices

[Here](https://math.unm.edu/graduate/thesis-and-dissertation-template) contains a template for a thesis. In style_sheets there's a template.tex file. The template works by editing that file and compiling. When one does so there is an appendix A and appendix B at the end of the pdf. I have used this write my thesis, but still am not able to remove appendix A and B. Erasing the appendix code in template.tex makes it where the file won't compile.

How can I remove the appendix chapters?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you make your question self-contained please as in include code here as well as linking to it, links can rot and die. Editing in the relevant template.tex code would suffice please

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need/want an appendix, just delete everything from (and including) `\chapter*{Appendices}` up to the end. That includes the whole `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}` block, `\appendix` and the two sample `\chapter`s.

Here is a reduced template, that compiles fine:

```
\documentclass[botnum, fleqn]{unmeethesis}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{An Awesome Thesis That Will Prove \\ to the Universe
       That I Really Deserve This Honorable Degree}

\author{Albert Richard Einstein, III}
\degreesubject{M.S., Mathematics}
\degree{Master of Science \\ Mathematics}
\documenttype{Thesis}

\previousdegrees{A.A.S., University of Southern Swampland, 1988 \\
                 M.S., Art Therapy, University of New Mexico, 1991}

\date{December, \thisyear}
\maketitle

\begin{dedication}
   To my parents.
\end{dedication}

\begin{acknowledgments}
   \vspace{1.1in}
   I would like to thank my advisor, Professor Martin Sheen.
\end{acknowledgments}

\maketitleabstract

\begin{abstract}
   The theory of relativity is a real ``toughie'' to prove.
\clearpage 
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\begin{glossary}{Longest  string}
   \item[$a_{lm}$]
      Taylor series coefficients, where $l,m = \{0..2\}$
   \item[$A_{\bf{p}}$]
      Complex-valued scalar denoting the amplitude and phase.
   \item[$A^T$]
      Transpose of some relativity matrix.
\end{glossary}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{\label{section:overview}Overview}
   The classic approach to proving a theorem is some really difficult 
   mathematics.  
\section{Conclusions}
   I conclude that this is a really short thesis.

\chapter{Future Work}
   I'm sure my future work will consist of lots of other famous stuff.

\end{document}
```

That said, in the future please make it easier for people to be able to help you: downloading a custom class and template, in zipped form no less, is really not something that most people will do very often. This is why you're always asked to provide an MWE on this SX.